# ExpressJs returns empty res.json

Tags: json, node.js, express

When validating a mongoose schema in 'pre' of parallel middleware

```
schema.pre('save', true, function (next, done) {
  if(...) {
     next(new Error('Some error message'));
  }
  next();
});
```

I return an error and it is available in the callback function:

```
model.save({},{}, function(err) {
  res.json(400, err);
  console.log(err)// I see in the console: [Error: 'Some error message']
})
```

But when I do

```
res.json(400, err);
```

I get an empty response

```
{} No properties
```

What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 3):

JSON can't stringify errors. You'll need to use something else to send the error.

Perhaps just `res.send(err.message)`, or something similar.